# Full wave rectifier reached the limit

Tags: operational-amplifier, rectifier

Can anyone tell me why the output of the full wave rectifier reached the limit (3.51V)? (Input voltage: Amptitude=4V; Power supply: 5V) Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 17):

The second OpAmp has an input common range that ends 1.5V below the positive supply. In this configuration the input common mode voltage is equal to input voltage, the circuit will only work up to about VDD - 1.5V which turns out to be 3.5V

From the datasheet:

[image]

You need to increase the supply voltage to increase the input common mode range or pick a different OpAmp.

Comment: @ppendless Please mark it as answered.